# How can I make Mirrored Button in iOS Camera?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want making mirroring button(left right reverse) in Camera.
But I don't know how to make. TnT

```
@IBAction func MirroringImage(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    func MirroringImage(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to mirror a single image, but not changing the image raw data, you can use `withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()` on your UIImage.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/2113668-withhorizontallyflippedorientati

If you want to change the image raw data, try this:

```
func flip(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, image.scale)
  let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

  bitmap.translateBy(x: image.size.width / 2, y: image.size.height / 2)
  bitmap.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: -1.0)

  bitmap.translateBy(x: -image.size.width / 2, y: -image.size.height / 2)
  bitmap.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))

  let out = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

  return out
}
```

If you are using AVCaptureSesstion, then you can use `isVideoMirrored` :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1389172-isvideomirrored

Comment: sure. don't forget to let me know the result